# How does reassigning a disposable object variable work?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

In C# when reassigning a disposable object variable with a new object, how does it work in the memory? Will the memory space occupied by the old object simply be overwritten by the new object? Or do I still have to call `Dispose()` to release the resources it uses?

```
DisposableThing thing;

thing = new DisposableThing();
//....do stuff
//thing.Dispose();
thing = new DisposableThing();
```

Comment: I don't know if you are aware or not, but since you tagged this question with [garbage-collection] & [idisposable], I thought I'd just say that the garbage collector never calls `IDisposable.Dispose()`. You must explicitly write your code so that `Dispose()` is called prior to the GC collecting it.

Comment: @Enigmativity The "Microsoft-ordained" examples all have the finalizer invoking `Dispose(false)` (I imagine this is done as a last ditch effort to ensure the external resources have a *chance* of being released). Granted both the GC and finalizers are fickle beasts and should generally not be relied upon where disposable objects are used... YMMV.

Comment: @pst - Yes, they do and I think that's where the confusion stems from. It's important for .NET developers to then also understand that there's no guarantee that the finalizer will ever be called, so one would need to make sure that one's `Dispose` method is "optional" if it were coded using this pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works the same as any other assignment: *`=` does not care about `IDisposable` or do any magic.*

The object initially assigned to the variable will have to have `Dispose` invoked manually (or better yet, with `using`) as required. However, it may not always be correct to call `Dispose` at this point: *who owns the object and controls the lifetime?*

> Will the memory space occupied by the old object simply be overwritten by the new object?

Does not apply. Variables "name" objects. An *object is itself* and a variable is a variable - not the object or "location in memory". (See Eric Lippert's comment bellow: the preceding is a high-level view of variables while Eric's comment reflects variables more precisely in C# implementation, spirit, and terminology.)

Variables only affect object lifetimes insomuch as they can* keep an object from being reclaimed (and thus prevent the finalizer from [possibly eventually] running). However, variables do not control the objects *semantic-lifetime* -- an object may be Disposed even when not reclaimable -- or eliminate the need to invoke `Dispose` as required.

Happy coding.

---

When dealing with disposable objects that extend beyond simple scopes -- the objects may be assigned to *many* different variables during their lifetime! -- I find it best to define who "takes control" which I annotate in the documentation. If the object lifetime is nicely limited to a scope then `using` works well.

*A local variable itself is not necessarily sufficient to keep an object strongly reachable as it is possible that the variable/assignment is aggressively optimized out if not used later from the same scope. This may plague objects like timers.

Comment: Thanks and great tips on documenting the controller! By 'aggressively optimized out' do you mean something like `obj a = new obj(); func(a)` will be optimized to `func(new obj());`?

Comment: @Dan7 Some information can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx in the warnings/example usage. Basically it means that the JIT could go: "Ah hah! You never use that variable again! Thus I might as well just forget it (and the object it named)" which in turn might make an object reclaimable and perhaps GC'ed if nothing else is keeping a strong reference to it.

Comment: Variables do not name *objects*. Variables (the ones that have names) name *storage locations*. Storage locations contain *references* to objects, if the variable is of reference type, or contain *objects* if the variable is of value type. Of course not all variables have names, and some have multiple names.

Comment: "Storage locations".  I like that term.  It could also be used to help clarify the difference between value types and reference types: a value-type storage location can be anywhere, and holds the data for a value type; a storage location of a class type can also be anywhere, but all it holds is a reference to data which is kept at some other location, whose existence and access must not depend upon the current thread or scope (typically the heap is used; certainly not the stack).

Comment: @Eric Lippert You are correct in that my answer was overly terse -- and the omission of of value types was critical. However, I find that -- in a high level language like C# -- it is simpler to deal with objects at a higher level, even if C# (and Java) still expose "references" in specification. I did not mean to imply that an object can ever have a single name (or that an object knows anything about the variables that "name" it); this use of a "variable naming an object" is much more common (read: accepted) in a language ecosystem such as Python, however.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you have one slot / reference and two instances of an `IDisposable` object.  Both of these instances must be disposed indepedently.  The compiler doesn't insert any magic for `IDisposable`.  It will simply change the instance the reference points to

A good pattern would be the following

```
using (thing = new DisposableThing()) {
  // ... do stuff
}

thing = new DisposableThing();
```

Ideally the second use of `thing` should also be done within a `using` block

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and common, for multiple references to the same IDisposable object to exist.  There is nothing wrong with overwriting or destroying all but one of those references, provided that one reference will have Dispose called on it before it is destroyed.

Note that the purpose of IDisposable.Dispose isn't actually to destroy an object, but rather to let an object which has previously asked other entities to do something on its behalf (e.g. reserve a GDI handle, grant exclusive use of a serial port, etc.), notify those entities that they no longer need to keep doing so.  If nothing tells the outside entities that they no longer need to keep doing something on behalf of the IDisposable object, they'll keep doing it--even if the object they're doing it for no longer exists.